# Increasing size of calendar

Tags: css, html

Is there are way to increase the size of my calendar https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/xtdjk8nr/1/ so that it takes up the entire screen without having to re-adjust margins, etc? Basically I want to expand it without having the structure or format change. I tried:

```
html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
 }
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
 }
```

But that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the .wrapper class

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```